# Convert mp3 to Ogg Vorbis with SoundConverter

Tags: mp3, convert, ogg-vorbis, soundconverter

Is there a way to set SoundConverter to 320kbps? I want to convert mp3 320kbps files to Ogg Vorbis 320 kbps. I see it is possible in SoundConverter to have it in 256 and 500 kbps but not in 320kbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of `sed` magic will simply and safely solve the issue for you. The following is a *single command*, simply copy the whole block and paste it into a Terminal window:

```
sudo sed -i_bak \
-e 's/quality_setting = {0: 0, 0.2: 1, 0.4: 2, 0.6: 3, 0.8: 4, 1.0: 5}/quality_setting = {0.2: 0, 0.4: 1, 0.6: 2, 0.8: 3, 0.9: 4, 1.0: 5}/' \
-e 's/quality = (0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)/quality = (0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)/' \
/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py
```

This can subsequently be *easily* reversed, if you ever wish to do so, by using the following `sed` one liner:

```
sudo mv -v /usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py_bak \
/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py
```

The results can be seen in this screenshot, note the 320kbps setting indicated with the mouse pointer:

[image]

This leaves you with the following bitrates available from within Soundconverter:

- Approximate bitrate ~96kbps
- Approximate bitrate ~128kbps
- Approximate bitrate ~192kbps
- Approximate bitrate ~256kbps
- Approximate bitrate ~320kbps
- Approximate bitrate ~500kbps

And the syntax of my `sed` example can easily be altered to allow for *other* quality settings and thus *different* bitrate combinations. Nice to have this available from within the application itself but this is what we have at the moment...

The Linux command line is so cool :)

**References:**

- [Recommended Encoder Settings for Ogg Vorbis](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Recommended_Ogg_Vorbis#Recommended_Encoder_Settings): The most solid recommendations for Ogg Vorbis, found in the Hydrogenaudio Knowledgebase.